# How to select multiple images in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mongodb, meteor

How can we select multiple images in a meteor application?

I could not find anything in https://github.com/sylvaingi/meteor-imagemagick

Can a jquery script run in meteor application?

```
$('img').live('click', function(){
var $this = $(this);
$this.toggleClass('selected');

if($this.hasClass('selected'))
    $this.next(':hidden').val($this.data('id'))
else
    $this.next(':hidden').val('');});$('form').submit(function(){
console.log($(this).serialize());
return false;
```

})

Comment: how is your front-end code related to database?

Comment: Images are stored in database, they retrieve it using fs collection package

Comment: but it is not related to the question (DOM manipulation with jquery is not really related to mongodb). You should not tag the question with `nginx`, `solaris`, because you happend to run it on nginx on solaris.

Comment: no I did not get you

Comment: The images are saved in mongo db

Comment: Why aren't you using meteor's template events?

Comment: ya using events to add functionality to click buttons